# Redirect page when Javascript is disabled

Tags: asp.net

I need to redirect to another page when the client script is disabled on the browser. Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: check this out http://groups.google.fr/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_frm/thread/19fe9b2c8ca234ce?hl=fr&lr=&rls=GGLD,GGLD:2003-51,GGLD:fr&rnum=7&prev=/groups%3Fq%3Djavascript%2Bdisabled%2Bhow%2Bto%26hl%3Dfr%26lr%3D%26rls%3DGGLD%252CGGLD%253A2003-51%252CGGLD%253Afr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I haven't tested this but it should work.**

Content inside `<noscript>` fires when there is no Javascript enabled, so you can do a `<meta />` redirect like this.

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=path-to-no-js-page.html"">
</noscript>
```

Comment: Yeah I've heard that the validator might complain about it before. Make sure you're placing it in the <head> of your page.

Comment: ok.. so confusing.. tried to put within the head element and outside the body element. I got error: noscript cannot be nested within element head!.

When I placed within the body element, the noscript will never get a chance to be triggered because all the javascript was placed executed within the head element so it gives an script error first

Comment: Message: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.

Message: 'Sys' is undefined

Comment: huh? Because of `<noscript>`? What happens in the other browsers?

Comment: ok.. here what I put in the master page (within body element): <NOSCRIPT> <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3; URL=../noscript.aspx"> </NOSCRIPT>. but it didn't redirect to noscript page

Comment: @user384080, what about placing it in the `<head>` element?

Comment: placing in the head will give me an error: noscript cannot be nested within element head

Comment: it's actually working place it in the head element. but i don't know why VS 2010 giving the intellisense error:  noscript cannot be nested within element head